# How do I make a function that accepts numVertices and numEdges then ALWAYS generates a connected graph?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm

- I want to generate a connected, *undirected* graph that contains n vertices and m edges. In particular, I want to generate a graph with nodes that contain exactly one of each integer from `0` to `n - 1`.
- I've looked somewhat deeply on this site and could not find what I was looking for. I will appreciate any help offered. Thanks!

Comment: Asking for software/library recommendations is explicitly off-topic, please see [help/on-topic], [ask].

Comment: @AMC I apologize for this! I’ve modified my question and explanation so that this is not the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about existing libraries but this is a solution from scratch. Suppose you have n nodes and m edges. To generate a simple (no duplicate edge), connected graph, m, n must satisfy this condition:

`n - 1 <= m <= n * (n - 1) / 2`

Process (nodes are indexed from 0 to n - 1):

1. Generate a spanning tree to make sure the graph is connected. There are many ways (for example, Prufer sequence), but here is a simple way:

`for i = 1 to n - 1:
     add_edge(i, randint(0, i - 1))`

To make it look more random, you can shuffle the order of nodes first.

2. Add more edges until you have m edges.

`while there are less than m edges:
     a, b = randint(0, n - 1), randint(0, n - 1)
     if (a != b and edge(a, b) has not existed):
        add_edge(a, b)`

Note: `randint(a, b)` = a random integer in range [a, b].

The codes look simple but work very fast in practice. You can calculate expected number of iterations to see why.

Comment: Thank you so much! I plan to try and use your method.